# RadGrid PopUp window opens in the area of a RadPageView

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadTabStrip in my page with a RadMultiPage, And I have a RadPageView for each tab in the RadMultiPage. I have a RadGrid in one of the RadPageViews. There is a FormEditSetting in my RadGrid that shows a popup for editing and inserting. the pop up window opens in the area of RadPageView and I can not move it around in the other parts of the page... which property should I set to keep the pop up window in front of the page?

Answer (score 0):

When you load an entire ppage in the PageView, it is actually loaded in an iframe, so one cannot take objects from inside (i.e., the grid edit form) and move them outside of the frame.

What you can consider is the following:

1. examine this demo to see how you can edit a RadGrid with a RadWindow: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window.
2. open the RadWindow from the topmost frame instead of the current frame. Something like var wnd = window.top.radopen() should do the trick. Note that you need a RadWindowManager on the top frame to do this
3. Pass data back to the calling frame by using the approach from this page: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/creating-parent-child-relationships-between-radwindows-and-passing-data-between-them - you can store the calling frame's window object in a custom field in the RadWindow object so you can pass data or call functions in it when needed.